# How to copy a Web Application or Site Collection structure without the content

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, backup, restore

I was wondering if it is possible to create a backup of a Web Application or (top level) Site Collection and restore it without the contents (documents) in order to preserve only the site structure (and features).

The gist is to create a copy of the production environment without the documents for a new development environment.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can save site collection as a template without including content. Then create new site collection based on that template.